# How Distributed Hash Table in IPFS and Bittorrent prevent abuse?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, ipfs, chord, kademlia

My understanding is that IPFS and Bittorrent Mainline DHT are built on top of a Distributed hash Table (Kademlia).
They use the file hash as Kademlia key to find a list of peer that might have this file.

1- What I don't understand is if this is all decentralized who remove from the DHT peer that no longer host a file content?

2- What prevent someone from storing large amount of data for free inside the DHT?

3- What prevent someone from disrupting the network by adding large number of invalid peer for a popular file.

4- What prevent a bad actor from joining the DHT ring and not following the routing protocol thus preventing discovery message from reaching correct nodes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why this was downvoted. These are excellent questions.

> 1- What I don't understand is if this is all decentralized who remove
>   from the DHT peer that no longer host a file content?

I think that DHT entries are regularly re-broadcast. So if a peer goes away, its DHT entries will no longer be broadcast and the network will forget about the data it provides unless some other node has it.

> 2- What prevent someone from storing large amount of data for free
>   inside the DHT?

Unless you re-publish or somebody else is interested in the data, it will vanish. The amount of data that you can store directly in a DHT entry is limited. So you can make other nodes store some of your data by putting data directly into DHT entries, but the effort outweighs the benefits.

> 3- What prevent someone from disrupting the network by adding large
>   number of invalid peer for a popular file.

I think there are some mechanisms *envisioned* in IPFS to protect the DHT against attacks. However, I don't think the current implementation is all that sophisticated. I don't think that current IPFS would deal well with a large scale distributed DDOS attack.

> 4- What prevent a bad actor from joining the DHT ring and not
>   following the routing protocol thus preventing discovery message from
>   reaching correct nodes.

I think a single node would be insufficient to do much damage, because a node will ask multiple peers. You would have to have multiple nodes to do significant damage.

But IPFS as it is now would not survive a sophisticated attack by state actors.

Comment: About #4 
 S/Kademlia nodes lookup values over disjoint paths, in order to ensure honest nodes can connect to each other in the presence of a large fraction of adversaries in the network. S/Kademlia achieves a success rate of 0.85 even with an adversarial fraction as large as half of the nodes.